Expressing $2^n$ as a Sum of Four Squares Using Quaternion Norms
The problem is to find the positive integer solutions to the Diophantine equation
$2^n = a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$. I was able to solve it using some modular arithmetic and a few case checks. The solutions I found are of the form $(2^x,0,0,0)$ ; $(2^x,2^x,0,0)$ ; $(2^x,2^x,2^x,2^x)$ and their permutations.
I was wondering if there is an easier way to solve this equation, perhaps by using norms, factorizations in quaternions, or a similar algebraic method.

Welcome to Math SE. For $n\ge 3$, consider what the parities of $a$, $b$, $c$ & $d$ must be. Also, using an Approach0 search, there's the AoPS thread Regional Olympiad - FBH 2009 Grade 11 Problem 2, and also the related Prove there are infinitely many positive integers which cannot be represented as a sum of four non-zero squares., where my answer relatively simply shows there are solutions for odd $n$.

What do you mean by solve?  Find all solutions?  Some?  Count solutions?
